# Tomcat Application randomly stops responding on AWS Linux Machine

Tags: linux, tomcat, amazon-ec2, amazon-cognito

Hi I am facing this error on AWS Linux machine randomly my tomcat stops responding and when I restart machine, it starts working fine.

Logs I get against this request are mentioned below

```
 org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service Error parsing HTTP request header
 Note: further occurrences of HTTP request parsing errors will be logged at DEBUG level.
    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid character found in method name [0x030x000x00+&0xe00x000x000x000x000x00Cookie:]. HTTP method names must be tokens
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11InputBuffer.parseRequestLine(Http11InputBuffer.java:413)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:261)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:868)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1590)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Exceptioncom.amazonaws.SdkClientException: Unable to execute HTTP request: cognito-idp.us-east-1.amazonaws.com
Exceptioncom.amazonaws.SdkClientException: Unable to execute HTTP request: cognito-idp.us-east-1.amazonaws.com
Exceptioncom.amazonaws.SdkClientException: Unable to execute HTTP request: cognito-idp.us-east-1.amazonaws.com
Exceptioncom.amazonaws.SdkClientException: Unable to execute HTTP request: cognito-idp.us-east-1.amazonaws.com
Exceptioncom.amazonaws.SdkClientException: Unable to execute HTTP request: cognito-idp.us-east-1.amazonaws.com
```

Comment: Looks to me like the app is trying to connect to Cognito repeatedly (probably the exponential backoff from the SDK), but can't and blocks.

Comment: thanks for response , actually on current scenario multiple users can login on application , most of times it works fine but sometimes it stops responding I am trying very hard but couldn't get any solution, please help me

Comment: Is that the only app in your VPC experiencing occasional connectivity issues? Is that the only 3rd Party API call you make, do the others always work?

Comment: only one app is deployed on tomcat and this app experience this issue , it is public machine

Comment: @Maurice it is my base authentication app all other apps deployed on other service and UI uses this service  for authentication, can you please suggest me what should I do

Comment: Maybe you're subject to throttling at the Cognito-API? I have no clue about the volume of traffic you're operating at, here's the [documentation with the default limits](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/limits.html) If you suspect that may be it, you can increase these limits or talk to AWS support.

Comment: thanks but same application is deployed in beta version and it is working fine, the only difference is that beta is AWS windows machine and other is  AWS linux machine, same application working fine on windows but causing error on linux machine as mentioned above ,

Comment: @Maurice is there any chance of Linux and tomcat conflict as on windows machine I haven't seen this issue so far

Comment: That's always an option, both are software solutions that consist of millions of lines of code - bugs are bound to happen, which is why you usually try to keep your different stages as close to one another in terms of Hard/Software as possible.